# Git: Trying to checkout a file I run into permission issues. Changing permissions doesn't solve it

Tags: git, file-permissions

I recently tried to checkout a project and couldn't because of a modified file.

I tried to `git checkout -- file.ext` but got the error:

> error: unable to unlink old 'file.ext' (Permission denied)

Thinking that perhaps the file was unwritable (and taking not from what I found online), I changed the permissions to 777 with chmod, `chmod 777 file.ext` and confirmed this had happened with `ls -l file.ext`.

However, the problem remains with the same error message.

Would anyone know why this is and how I could fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need write access to the directory that contains `file.ext`. You can't delete (unlink) files in a directory unless you have write access to that directory - the permissions of the file in question do not matter.

Comment: Thanks that worked! The directory was the root directory of my site. I wonder why no other files were affected.